# how to manage Qthreads when I create many thread use timer?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to create some Qthreads with a Qtimer, but after a few seconds, The program will exit suddenly, So I want to know how to manage those threads to make use of thread more reasonable?

use PyQt5, QThread,

```py
self.time_flash.timeout.connect(self.start_face)

def open_face(self):
     # when I make time bigger
     # The program will run more long time before auto exit.
     time = 3000
    self.time_flash.start(time)    

def start_face(self):
          self.thread = ResThread()
          self.thread.start()
```

I want to know the reason about the auto exit.  maybe it is about out of memory?  And I want to know how to fix it.  (Thanks)

Comment: I think that `.thread` attribute is used by qt and you are overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

`.thread` attribute is part of  Qobject api and you are overwriting it. Just replace `self.thread` by something else and you should be fine

Here is the doc https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qobject.html#thread

Comment: other problem cause the program auto exit,,,